# Why doesnt scanf read the buffered input for int?

Tags: c, scanf

Case I

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){

    char c;
    int i;
    scanf("%c",&c);

    scanf("%d",&i);
    printf("%d",i);
}

Input:a
      23

Output:23
```

Case II

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    char c;
    int i;
    scanf("%c",&c);
    printf("%c",c);

    scanf("%c",&c);
    printf("%c",c);
}

Input:a
OutPut:a
```

Why in case II only one input is required while in case I two inputs are required?

**If in case II its reading the buffered characters why is n't the same thing happening in Case I?**

Comment: You really should test the resulting item count of [`scanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf)

Answer (score 1):

`scanf("%c",&c)` reads a *character* (and could fail; read carefully about [`scanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf))

`scanf("%d",&i)` reads an *integer* (and could fail)

What is a character? Well, 'a' is a character, but so is whitespace characters such as newline.
When you enter a and press enter into the terminal input, you are sending both an a and a newline to the buffered input. The first scanf will read the a, and the second scanf will read the newline.

When you do `scanf("%c",&c); scanf("%d",&i);` on the other hand, the first scanf will read the 'a' character. The second scanf will look for an integer, but since only whitespace (a newline) is available in the buffer it will skip over the whitespace and wait for something that it can parse as a number becomes available.